# How do I make a drill rotate using shape keys?

Tags: animation, shape-keys

I'm making a few drills and wanting to make them rotate at the same time, I am wondering how to do this using shape keys, because it's not going to be animated yet. I'm going to use the cycles modifier for making it loop.

Comment: why do you want to do that with shapekeys? It doesn't seem like the most logical way to do it...

Comment: Shape keys only have linear interpolation which is not good for rotations. Also what is a "*cycles modifier*"?

Comment: @Duarte Farrajota Ramos https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/graph_editor/fcurves/modifiers.html#cycles. I agree, you can't make it with shape keys. Make only rotation keyframes without location and use the same action for every drill.

Comment: Hum, right; F-Curve modifiers. Was thinking about object ones.